# Which SE site would be the appropriate place to ask about discovering search engine key-words?

Tags: discussion, search, site-recommendation

I Google frequently to find answers. Unfortunately, sometimes the questions I want answered require me to use search terms that I don't know. Any subdomain of knowledge develops its own jargon, and if I am not expert enough in that domain, I don't know the jargon enough to find the precise keywords that help me answer my question.

Some example searches I have done in the past include looking for the word or phrase for the cap/cover that goes over the end of a USB drive and the plate that sits under a planter to catch water overflow.

Even if I have seen a physical object and know what it is used for, the Google search terms I need must match the keywords used by the people who make the webpages I am searching for.

My question is, what method would help me discover keywords that I don't currently know yet to use in a search engine?

I suspect this question might work in either the SE english usage or webmaster sites, but I am open to recommendations.

Comment: Presumable Google questions belong on [Webapps.se], though the question will be one of expertise in the specific domain you're investigating (in other words: I imagine the question will be on-topic there, but that doesn't guarantee you'll get detailed answers).